# PL/SQL Numeric or value error: character to number conversion error

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

Procedure Code:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE GetOrder(
p_Order IN NUMBER, 
p_OrderDate OUT DATE, 
p_CusNbr OUT NUMBER, 
p_OrderOut OUT NUMBER, 
p_Name OUT VARCHAR2, 
p_Address OUT VARCHAR2,
p_City OUT VARCHAR2, 
p_State OUT CHAR,
p_Zip OUT NUMBER,
p_Itm OUT NUMBER,
p_Desc OUT VARCHAR2,
p_Qty OUT NUMBER,
p_Price OUT NUMBER) 
AS
v_OrderDate ord.ord_date%type;
v_CusNbr ord.Cus_nbr%type;
v_Order ord.Ord_nbr%type;
v_Name cus.cus_nme%type;
v_Address cus.str_adr%type;
v_City zip.city%type;
v_state zip.st%type;
v_Zip zip.zip%type;
v_Itm itm.itm_nbr%type;
v_Desc itm.ITM_DSC%TYPE;
v_Qty ord_itm.ord_Qty%type;
v_Price itm.ord_itm_price%type;
BEGIN
SELECT O.ORD_NBR, C.CUS_NBR, O.ORD_DATE, C.CUS_NME, C.STR_ADR, Z.CITY, Z.ST, I.ITM_NBR, I.ITM_DSC, OI.ORD_QTY, I.ORD_ITM_PRICE
       INTO
       v_Order, v_CusNbr, v_OrderDate, v_Name, v_Address, v_Zip, v_state, v_Itm, v_Desc, v_Qty, v_Price
FROM ITM I JOIN ORD_ITM OI ON (I.ITM_NBR = OI.ITM_NBR) 
           JOIN ORD O ON (OI.ORD_NBR = O.ORD_NBR)
           JOIN CUS C ON (O.CUS_NBR = C.CUS_NBR)
           JOIN ZIP Z ON (C.ZIP_ADR = Z.ZIP)
WHERE O.ORD_NBR = p_Order;
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('ILLINOIS COMPUTERS');
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('CUSTOMER ORDER FORM');
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(v_Order || v_OrderDate || v_CusNbr);
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Name: ' || v_Name);
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Address: ' || v_Address);
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('City: ' || v_City || ' State : ' || v_state || ' Zip: ' || v_Zip);
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Item No.' || 'Description' || 'Quantity' || 'Price');
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(v_Itm || v_Desc || v_Qty || v_Price);
END GetOrder;
/
```

And when I call the procedure:

```
DECLARE
    p_OrderNbr NUMBER := &ordernumber;
    p_OrderDateOutput   DATE;
    p_CusNbrOutput      NUMBER;
    p_OrderNbrOutput    NUMBER;
    p_NameOutput        cus.cus_nme%type; 
    p_AddressOutput     cus.str_adr%type;
    p_CityOutput        zip.city%type; 
    p_StateOutput       CHAR;
    p_ZipOutput         NUMBER;
    p_ItmOutput         NUMBER;
    p_DescOutput        itm.itm_dsc%type;
    p_QtyOutput         NUMBER;
    p_PriceOutput       NUMBER;
begin
    GetOrder(p_OrderNbr, 
    p_OrderDateOutput, 
    p_CusNbrOutput, 
    p_OrderNbrOutput,
    p_NameOutput,
    p_AddressOutput,
    p_CityOutput,
    p_StateOutput, 
    p_ZipOutput,
    p_ItmOutput,
    p_DescOutput,  
    p_QtyOutput, 
    p_PriceOutput);
END;
/
```

I'm getting

> ORA-06502 error: numeric or value error: character to number
>   conversion error.

I believe all my parameters are in order so I'm not getting conflicting variable assignments.

I ran this query seperately to make sure I'm getting the right output and it works fine.

```
SELECT O.ORD_NBR, C.CUS_NBR, O.ORD_DATE, C.CUS_NME, C.STR_ADR, Z.CITY, Z.ST, I.ITM_NBR, I.ITM_DSC, OI.ORD_QTY, I.ORD_ITM_PRICE
       --INTO
       --v_Order, v_CusNbr, v_OrderDate, v_Name, v_Address, v_Zip, v_state, v_Itm, v_Desc, v_Qty, v_Price
FROM ITM I JOIN ORD_ITM OI ON (I.ITM_NBR = OI.ITM_NBR) 
           JOIN ORD O ON (OI.ORD_NBR = O.ORD_NBR)
           JOIN CUS C ON (O.CUS_NBR = C.CUS_NBR)
           JOIN ZIP Z ON (C.ZIP_ADR = Z.ZIP)
WHERE O.ORD_NBR = 100;
```

Comment: p_OrderNbr NUMBER := &ordernumber; why this & sign?

Comment: What have you done to debug the problem?  Normally, I wouldn't write this much code without running it at least once, I'd start with a query that returned one column, validate that, add additional columns, validate that, etc. until I had the full query.  You can go in reverse and remove some columns until you figure out which step is throwing the error.  If you can pinpoint where the error is occurring but still have a problem understanding how to fix it, we can probably be more helpful.

Comment: FYI, your anonymous block must not be the one you're actually using to call your procedure.  You can't declare a variable to be `CHAR` without a length.  If you did, you should get a different error.

Comment: The ampersand is to receive input for the order number. Is that wrong?

Comment: Justin, what do you mean by anonymous block? I also had p_NameOutput, p_AddressOutput, p_CityOutput, and p_DescOutput as VARCHAR2 and I received errors saying I violated the string length (1.. 32000).

Comment: Check the edit to the original post. I ran this query to make sure I got the right output before inserting into variables, and that worked fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Select list says

```
 ... C.STR_ADR, Z.CITY, Z.ST, ...
```

Into list says

```
 ... v_Address, v_Zip, v_state ...
```

Seems you got the wrong field in Z table.

Unless Z.CITY is the numeric zip code?

Comment: Yep... that was it. Thanks for catching that.

Comment: @Josh -- yw.  I'm feeling very pleased with myself for figuring it out without see the table definitions.